# Delegate's function returns nil

Tags: swift, delegates

I followed a delegation tutorial in Objective C quite grasped the concept, and then try to implement it in swift.

I have a custom view inheriting "AppController" class, and a NSObject inheriting "SquareView" class.

AppContoller.swift

```
import Cocoa

class AppController: NSObject,SquareViewDelegate {
var squareCount:Int = 10

    @IBOutlet var squareView: SquareView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        squareView.needsDisplay = true
    }

    @IBAction func changeSquareCount(sender:AnyObject) {
        squareCount = Int(sender.intValue)
        squareView.needsDisplay = true
    }

    func numberOfSquaresInQuareView(squareView: SquareView) -> Int {
        return squareCount
    }
}
```

SquareView.swift

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

protocol SquareViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSquaresInQuareView(squareView:SquareView)->Int
}

class SquareView: NSView {

    var delegate: SquareViewDelegate!

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        NSColor.redColor().set()
        let num: Int = delegate.numberOfSquaresInQuareView(self)
        for _ in 0..<num {
            let x:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) % CGFloat(self.frame.size.width - 20)
            let y:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) % CGFloat(self.frame.size.width - 20)
            NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(x, y, 10, 10))
        }
    }
}
```

When I build and run, my delegate.numberOfSquaresInSquareView returns nil.
I feel like I haven't linked the delegate properly but I don't know how.

(I'm sorry, I know many people have ask this question already, but their answers still confuse me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set your AppController to be the SquareView delegate, so it won't be called.

Try with the code below, it should work.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    squareView.needsDisplay = true
    squareView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: It works! thank you! I have been trying to do the opposite, setting delegate in SquareView = AppController.

Comment: Glad to hear, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you assign the delegate? In AppController you have to assign the value of the the delegate.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    squareView.needsDisplay = true
    squareView.delegate = self
}
```

And then in SquareView, put weak to the delegate, make it  optional and assign to nil:

```
weak var delegate: SquareViewDelegate? = nil;
```

In DrawRect use the the delegate like this

```
let num: Int = delegate?.numberOfSquaresInQuareView(self)
```

Comment: Thank you! since I have accepted an answer, I'd give you +1.